# Need An Image Editor Package For Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-image

I need an image editor package for flutter with which I would be able to undo and redo any edits. Additionally, I would be able to move the drawing after selecting it and save it to the local database.

I have used "[image_painter](https://pub.dev/packages/image_painter)" and "[flutter_painter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_painter)" packages but unfortunately, none of them fulfilled my requirements.

It would be a great help if anyone could provide me with any information about a suitable flutter package. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want image crop and resizer etc..? or painter like photoshop?

Comment: I used "flutter_painter" and except for freehand drawing moving, it satisfied almost all the requirements.